# I have added 4 radio buttons but I cant find my radio group as i need its id

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-group

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sachin Tendulkar" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rahul Dravid" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Brain Lara" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="AB De Villiers" />
```

This is my code I cant find radio group..I have put 4 radio buttons but cant find radio group in xml file.

Comment: Fixed typo. Added android tags.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do following

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogrp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: glad it worked. Why don't you click on accept answer